# C++ File I/O skipping line every new iteration, why?

Tags: c++, file-io

Why is the program skipping the first line of every new deptnum?

I am trying to read from a file that looks like:

```
1 Suits   0300 100 092
1 Coats   0200 060 065
1 Shirts  1000 012 013
2 Dresses 0400 060 065
2 Coats   0185 184 200
2 Shoes   0600 040 030
3 Jeans   0200 040 035
3 Shoes   0200 030 034
4 Jeans   0300 042 043
```

The deptnum is the first column.

And when I write to the other file I get:

```
                    Blinn Discount Apparel Company
                        Inventory Evaluation
                            10/12/2018

                     Unit Cost              Extended
      Quantity     Cost    Market       Cost     Market     Lower Cost
Mens Dept
 Suits         300   100.00     92.00     30000.00  27600.00
 Coats         200    60.00     65.00     12000.00  13000.00
 Shirts       1000    12.00     13.00     12000.00  13000.00
  Total                                  $54000.00 $53600.00    $53600.00
Womens Dept
 Coats         185   184.00    200.00     34040.00  37000.00
 Shoes         600    40.00     30.00     24000.00  18000.00
  Total                                  $112040.00 $108600.00    $108600.00
Girls Dept
 Shoes         200    30.00     34.00      6000.00   6800.00
  Total                                  $118040.00 $115400.00    $115400.00
Boys Dept
  Total                                  $118040.00 $115400.00    $115400.00
Total Inventory                                             $393000.00
```

It skipped Womens Dept -> Dresses, Girls Dept -> Jeans, and Boys Dept -> Jeans.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

int x = 1, deptnum, quant,cost,mkt,extcost,extmkt,totalcost = 0,totalmkt = 0,
lowcost,totalInv = 0;
char item [15];

inFile.open("blinn.dat");
outFile.open("blinn.dout");

if (!inFile)
    cout <<"\n\t\t Can't open data file: blinn.dat\n";


    else {
    outFile <<"\n\t                    Blinn Discount Apparel Company\n";
    outFile <<"\t                        Inventory Evaluation\n";
    outFile <<"\t                            10/12/2018\n";
    outFile <<"\n\t\t\t\t\t\t Unit Cost\t\t\t    Extended\n";
    outFile <<"\t\t  Quantity     Cost    Market       Cost     Market     Lower Cost";

    while (x < 5)
    {
        if (x == 1)
            outFile << "\nMens Dept";
        else if (x == 2)
            outFile << "\nWomens Dept";
        else if (x == 3)
            outFile << "\nGirls Dept";
        else if (x == 4)
            outFile << "\nBoys Dept";
        else
            break;

        while (inFile >> deptnum >> item >> quant >> cost >> mkt)
        {

            if (deptnum == x){

            extcost = quant * cost;
            extmkt = quant * mkt;

            outFile << left << "\n " << setw(7)<< item << "      "
                << right << setw(4)<< quant << "  "
                << right << setw(4) << cost << ".00    "
                << right << setw(3) << mkt << ".00     "
                << right << setw(5) << extcost<< ".00  "
                << right << setw(5) << extmkt << ".00";

                totalcost += extcost;
                totalmkt += extmkt;

                if (totalcost > totalmkt)
                    lowcost = totalmkt;
                else
                    lowcost = totalcost;


            }else
                break;
                }

            outFile << right << "\n  Total\t\t\t\t\t                 $" << totalcost << ".00 $"
                    << totalmkt << ".00    $"<< lowcost << ".00";

        x += 1;

            totalInv += lowcost;
    }
        }

outFile << "\nTotal Inventory\t\t\t\t\t\t                        $"<< totalInv<< ".00";


inFile.close ();
outFile.close ();

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: Now is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger. Your debugger allows you to run your program one line at a time; inspect the values of all variables, as they change; and observe your program's logical behavior, and why it does exactly what it does. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. The logical flaw in the shown code appears to be simple, and I'm sure that once you use your debugger to trace how each line of the input line gets read and what happens to it, you'll figure it out in no time at all. Good luck.

Comment: Many thanks to @Sam Varshavchik for mentioning the degugger, It's so useful i can't believe my teacher didn't even mention it in class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your logic:

```
if (deptnum == x) {
    // do something
}
else {
    break;
}
```

To achieve the `else` branch, you have already read a line that `deptnum != x` (the first line of every new `deptnum`) so at the next iterator, the current line is discarded by the next input line.